# Jquery.onBlur только выбранный элемент, без дочерних

Tags: jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $(function() {
    $(".A").focus();
  });
  $(".A").blur(function() {
    alert(0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A" tabIndex="1">
  <input type="text>
   <a href=" ">Tra-ta-ta</a>
   <div>
        <input type=text">
</div>
</div>
```

Событие срабатывает, даже если я устанавливаю фокус в текстовые поля, которые являются дочерними "A". Как сделать, что бы blur не срабатывал на дочерних элементах?

Comment: надо, чтобы blur срабатывал или не срабатывал?

Comment: Вы js-код скопировали не полностью, первой строки не хватает.

Comment: `$(function () { 
 $(function () {
        $(".A").focus();
    });
    $(".A").blur(function () {
        alert(0);
    });
});`

Answer (score 1):

Если вариант с `$('.A input');` не подходит, то я рекомендую просто сверять элементы в событии.

```
$('.A').blur(function (evt) {
    if (evt.currentTarget !== evt.target) return;

    alert('0');
});
```

`evt.currentTarget` - элемент на который мы привязали событие.

`evt.target` - элемент на котором реально произошло событие.

Следует уточнить, что события `focus` и `blur` предназначены для **input**.
На блоки же лучше повесить событие `mousedown` и `mouseup`

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам поможет использование события [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) вместо blur.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.A').bind('focusin focusout', function () {
     $(this).toggleClass('showup');
 });
});
```

```css
.A {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    background:black;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}

input { 
    width:80px;
    margin:5px; 
}

.showup { background: #aaa;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="A">
   <input type="text">
   <a href="#">Tra-ta-ta</a>
   <div>
        <input type="text">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но меня не правильно поняли, Если устанавливается событие Focus на какой-то блок, то событие blur для него не должно срабатывать, если я щелкаю по дочерним элементам

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".A input").blur(function() {
    alert(0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A" tabIndex="1">
  <input type="text">
  <a href="">Tra-ta-ta</a>
  <div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но меня не правильно поняли, Если устанавливается событие Focus на какой-то блок, то событие blur для него не должно срабатывать, если я щелкаю по дочерним элементам.

Comment: Попробуйте через mousedown вне этого блока